# How do I calculate the size of a 3D translated element (with perspective)?

Tags: css

Imagine I have a layout like so:

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

and styled like so:

```
.outer {
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.inner {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,100px);
}
```

How can I (indeed, can I at all?) calculate what the size of this will be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll try to explain it "in depth"

[image]

In the case of css, perspective value defines (in pixels) how far the camera(look at image above) is from the yellow plane(screen) This value is inversely proportional to the distortion : the closer - the wider pyramid. [css3-transforms Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/)

So here is [translation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29) for the `translate3d(0,0,100px);`

```
      t
1 0 0 0   //x
0 1 0 0   //y
0 0 1 100 //z
0 0 0 1
```

Say we have 4 corners(points) of the element with the coordinates:

```
  p1 p2 p3 p4
X 0  1  0  1
Y 0  0  1  1
Z 1  1  1  1 // parallel to the screen.
  1  1  1  1
```

Let's apply `translate3d(0,0,100px);`  to the `p3`:

[image]

The final position `p3'` will be  multiplication of the `translation matrix` and the position vector `p3`:

```
   translation     p3      p3' 
    1 0 0 0        0       0
    0 1 0 0    X   1   =   1
    0 0 1 100      1       101
    0 0 0 1        1       1
```

The matrix for the css perspective projection with the identity matrix for perspective-origin(x and y position of the camera) will look like this:

[image]

```
1 0  0              0
0 1  0              0
0 0  1              0 
0 0 -1/perspective  1
```

Now multiply `perspective projection matrix`(with 1000px perspective) and `p3'` to apply perspective projection:

```
  perspective projection matrix     p3'      
    1 0  0      0                   0        0
    0 1  0      0         X         1     =  1       
    0 0  1      0                   101      101
    0 0 -0.001  1                   1        0.899 //w
```

`w` for the perspective projections serves as a scaling factor. And  on screen position of the `p3'` will be `x = x/w = 0` and `y = y/w = 1.112` so we can repeat it for the other 3 point and finally calculate distance between them `d = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)`  to find new width and height or just scale original width and height in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the very in depth answer. After a little head scratching I've got there!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jAre

This also has a simpler solution.

```
w = element.offsetWidth // elements width befor translate
z = 100                 // translateZ
p = 1000                // perspective

widthAfterTranslate = w/((z/p)+1)
```

The explanation is a little complicated, and considering that this question has already been answered, perhaps there is no need to explain it, but since it is important to reduce the size of the code, I wrote this answer and you can confirm the correctness of the answer by trying different values